# JavaScript conditional not short circuiting like I would expect

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I am an experienced developer, but I just ran into an issue that took me a while to figure out and am looking for an explanation. I was relying on short circuiting and spent more time than I care to admit debugging this. If this belongs on another Stack Exchange site, please advise.

I expect the following to evaluate to false, but it passes:

```
(false && true || true) => true
```

It is as though it's being interpreted as this:

```
((false && true) || true) => true
```

... but the solution is this:

```
(false && (true || true)) => false
```

Why doesn't `false` short circuit the operation in the first example? Is there some sort of lookahead I don't know about?

---

Solution summary: For those who (like me) never knew conditional operators have a similar precedence as mathematical operators - the same concept of *implied parenthesis* applies:

```
3 * 2 + 1 => (3 * 2) + 1 => 7
false && true || true => (false && true) || true => true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical AND (`&&`) has a higher precedence than logical OR (`||`).

You could fix the problem by adding the parentheses you used in your example.

```
x && (y || z);
```

However, it would be much more readable to use an explicit `if` statement instead:

```
if (x && y) {
    z;
}
```

[Here's a reference chart for operator precedence in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). (See #13 and #14.)

If you're having a hard time understanding precedence, try substituting `*` for `&&` and `+` for `||`:

```
x * y + z;
```

Clearly, by order of operations, the `x * y` will be executed first. So if you want to execute the `y + z` first instead, you would use parentheses.

Short circuiting has nothing to do with the syntax. It's simply a quirk of boolean operators. So don't think of it like

> I always thought that the first failed condition short circuits the operation and further evaluation stops.

The short circuiting doesn't call some sort of "abort" function that exits the entire operation. It's simply that the boolean operators will ignore their second argument (`b` in `a && b`) if it's already ascertainable what the final result will be. (For example, `false && (anything)` is always false, so `&&` is lazy and doesn't bother evaluating the second argument.)

> I still don't get how `false && (anything)` is always false but `false && (anything) || somethingelse` can be true.

Okay, so applying the precedence rules, we get:

```
(false && anything) || somethingelse
```

Therefore, the `&&` is evaluated first. Since it's lazy, it sees the `false` and immediately returns `false`:

```
(false) || somethingelse // `anything' is not evaluated
```

Now it's `||`'s turn to evaluate. It sees the `false` that `&&` just returned, and it can't short-circuit because `false || true` could still be true. So it has to evaluate the `somethingelse` to get the final result.

Therefore, the code `if((false && anything) || somethingelse)` is essentially equivalent to `if (somethingelse)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  My real code uses if statements and business logic. I just wanted to simplify it for posting here `if(false && true || true) { /* do stuff */ }`.  I guess I don't understand how precedence affects the outcome.  I always thought that the first failed condition short circuits the operation and further evaluation stops.

Comment: ... and thanks for the further explanation.  This is a new concept - not sure how it has averted me for 10 years.  I can accept in a couple minutes.

Comment: I still don't get how *`false && (anything)` is always false* but `false && (anything) || somethingelse` can be true.  No need for further explanation... off to do research.

Comment: @RyanWheale Ooh, that's a good question. Hang on, I'm going to edit another paragraph into my answer anyway for the benefit of future readers.